# Dynamic content only partially styled in JQuery Mobile/Phonegap

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a JQuery Mobile/Phonegap app. After dynamically inserting the html form elements I call `.trigger('create')` on the containing element, like so:

```
$('div#response-form').append(formHtmlString).trigger('create');
```

All the elements are correctly styled except the radio buttons and check boxes, which are only partially styled and also not properly aligned. See attached image below:

[image: Dynamic form in JQuery Mobile]

What on earth am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

**Edit**

This is the HTML code contained in the `formHTMLString` variable:

```
<form data-response_id="API1201344135246">
<div data-page="1">
    <h3>Page One</h3>
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend>Question - Checkbox*</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="10010" id="10010" value="One"  class="custom" />
        <label for="10010">One</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="10011" id="10011" value="Two"  class="custom" />
        <label for="10011">Two</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="10012" id="10012" value="Three"  class="custom" />
        <label for="10012">Three</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="2">Question - String*</label>
    <input type="text" name="2" id="2" value="" />
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend>Question - Radio Button</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="6" id="10004" value="Yes"  />
        <label for="10004">Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="6" id="10005" value="No"  />
        <label for="10005">No</label>
        <input type="radio" name="6" id="10006" value="Maybe"  />
        <label for="10006">Maybe</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>

....

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

If you want to use your custom theme/style, load jQuery-Mobile default CSS and override its' styles.

---

Enhance the markup of Checkbox and Radio buttons dynamically using both `.checkboxradio()` and `.trigger('create')`.

**Checkbox:**

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').checkboxradio().trigger('create');
```

**Radio button:**

```
$('input[type=radio]').checkboxradio().trigger('create');
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Pauph/)**

Comment: `$('body').trigger('create');` works in your demo as well (see http://jsfiddle.net/X43HK/), but neither works in my application, so calling `trigger('create')` on the parent container should have done the trick. You will see that it is __partially__ styled so it does do __something__. This issue seems to be a bit more complicated. Any other ideas?

Comment: @raouldeveloper are you overriding JQM styles? its working normally http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/MeA5M/

Comment: Hi Omar, this must be an Android or Webkit-related CSS issue. Just downloaded stock standard CSS files from jquerymobile.com, same issues. Also, I just added a navbar which also has issues, the selected button in the navbar shows perfectly, while the unselected ones show as simple links, completely unstyled.

Comment: Sorry Omar, this was it! Create a formal answer and I will mark as correct.

Comment: @raouldeveloper hi, was it a CSS issue? So I update my answer above. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, so when I use a custom theme CSS file with the JQuery structure (themeless) CSS file I ran into problems. What I ended up doing is using the default theme file (theme and structure in one) and then overriding it with my custom theme file. Obviously this is a bit larger than using the structure file only but it solves the problem. This is a bit odd and may be a bug, but you pointed me in the right direction..

Comment: @raouldeveloper I'm glad you got it solved. I usually override JQM styles rather than using a custom theme, I find it safer.